# Is this grammatical: "Relax while you're closing your eyes to me"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning, prepositional-phrases

I  understand what this means. But, I cannot figure out if this is grammatical or not because of *to me*:

> Relax while you're closing your eyes to me.

Do you *close your eyes to someone* when you close your eyes in front of him/her?

Is it idiomatic?

> Relax while you're closing your eyes in front of me.

makes sense to me,  but not when **to me** is used.

Comment: We use the expression *closing your eyes to* when we are speaking about unwelcome events or developments - not about people. Hence the proverb: *None so blind as those who will not see*. So you are right.

Comment: To be honest, neither sounds idiomatic to me. It almost sounds like poetry. Are you trying to say something like "You should relax and close your eyes", meaning "take a nap"/"rest"?

Comment: No, it isn't really very well said. Relax and close your eyes while facing me. But really, why not just: /Relax and close your eyes/?

Comment: I really don't know :) I can visualize it but I can't figure out why it's constructed like that. I don't make sense, I know.

Comment: In your example, "closing your eyes" is just something you do. It does not have any relationship to others, unless it is known from other context. So I don't see any reason for "me", just use "Relax while you're closing your eyes." However, if you asked this person to close their eyes, then you could use "Relax while you're closing your eyes *for* me." More context, please.

Answer (score 2):

Most prepositions are used idiomatically. There isn't really anything grammatically wrong with your first statement:

> Relax while you're closing your eyes to me.

But it does sound foreign or unusual to English speakers, because we wouldn't usually close our eyes *at* someone or something.

I think I am basically agreeing with your assessment.

Comment: I am not a native speaker, so it is tenfold more difficult to/for me :P But, thanks for explaining. I think now it makes sense why it does not make sense to me.